# composed_of updates ActiveRecord attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Example object:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  composed_of :bar, 
               mapping: [%w[user_id user_id], %w[color color]],
               converter: proc { |user_id, color| Bar.new(user_id, color) }
end

class Bar
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :user_id, :color

  def initialize(user_id, color)
    @user_id = user_id
    @color = color
  end
  
  def change_to_blue
    self.color = "blue"
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make it so if I update the bar object's color it also updates the Foo color?

Example

```
foo = Foo.last
foo.color = "yellow"
foo.bar.change_to_blue
puts foo.color
```

Currently the above would result in "yellow" but was wondering if it was possible to create the linkage back to Foo so that result is "blue"? I want to be able to do Foo.save! and the color would be updated to "blue"

Comment: `color = "blue"` - this does absolutely nothing. If you want to call the `attr_accessor`'s writer, do  `self.color = "blue"`.

Comment: Sorry, I did mess up the example when converting it from the real version. I edited the post to include the `self.color = blue`. The issue still persists with the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html) explain this concept fairly well.

> Active Record implements aggregation through a macro-like class method called `composed_of` for representing attributes as value objects.

> Value objects are immutable and interchangeable objects that represent a given value...It's also important to treat the value objects as immutable. Don't allow the [Bar] object to have its [color] changed after creation. Create a new [Bar] object with the new value instead.

Additionally I believe your `converter` is incorrect as the converter is used in assignment and thus only passes a single value.

So I think the below is actually what you are looking for to change the color.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  composed_of :bar, 
               mapping: [%w[user_id user_id], %w[color color]],
               constructor: proc { |user_id, color| Bar.new(user_id, color) }
end

class Bar
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :user_id, :color

  def initialize(user_id, color)
    @user_id = user_id
    @color = color
  end
  
  def change_to_blue
    self.class.new(user_id,'blue')
  end
end
```

and then

```
foo = Foo.last
foo.color = "yellow"
foo.bar = foo.bar.change_to_blue
puts foo.color
```